How can i build a Flutter comment widget that switches between IconButton and TextField with smooth a transition?
In Flutter, I have built a carousel PageView for a list of widgets (media files). I want a seamless way to add comments to the currentPage widget. I don't want a TextField permanently attached at the bottom, but switch from IconButton to TextField upon user engagement. What I have right now works, but it's really ugly :/
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final int? initialIndex;
  final List<String> items;
  const MyWidget({super.key, this.initialIndex, required this.items});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  late int _currentPage;
  late final PageController _controller =
      PageController(initialPage: widget.initialIndex ?? _currentPage);
  final commentFN = FocusNode();
  bool _hasFocus = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _currentPage = widget.initialIndex ?? 0;
    _controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        _currentPage = _controller.page!.toInt();
      });
    });

    commentFN.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        _hasFocus = commentFN.hasFocus;
      });
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('${_currentPage + 1} of 10'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTapDown: (details) {
              if (details.localPosition.dx <
                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2) {
                _currentPage == 0
                    ? null
                    : _controller.previousPage(
                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                        curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                      );
              } else {
                _currentPage == widget.items.length - 1
                    ? context.pop(context)
                    : _controller.nextPage(
                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                        curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                      );
              }
            },
            child: PageView.builder(
              controller: _controller,
              itemCount: widget.items.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Center(child: Text(widget.items[index]));
              },
            ),
          ),
          _hasFocus
              ? Positioned(
                  bottom: 0,
                  left: 15,
                  right: 15,
                  child: TextField(
                    focusNode: commentFN,
                    autofocus: _hasFocus,
                  ),
                )
              : Positioned(
                  bottom: 20,
                  right: 15,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _hasFocus = true;
                          });
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.comment),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.face),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    commentFN.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}


use AnimatedCrossFade - the docs say: "A widget two cross-fades between two given children and animates itself between their sizes.", two minute video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PGK2UUAyE54
